# windows property in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am using css and found a "windows"  property there, I am not getting the purpose of "windows" property in css.

```
widows:inherit;
widows:initial;
```

Comment: `Windows` or `widows`? [**Widows @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/widows)

Comment: I would like to say that it is pretty much useless right now and make sure you read the docs before posting questions which can be easily answered via google search

Comment: Also, its **not an attribute**, its a **property**

Comment: its "windows" not "Windows"

Comment: its `widows` not `windows`

Answer (score 6):

That's because isn't `windows`, but `widows` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/widows). If it's written `windows`is a misspelling error.

`widows` purpose is perfectly defined in the previously cited site:

> The widows CSS property defines how many minimum lines must be left on
>   top of a new page, on a paged media. In typography, a widow is the
>   last line of a paragraph appearing alone at the top of a page. Setting
>   the widows property allows to prevent widows to be left.
>
> On a non-paged media, like screen, the widows CSS property has no
>   effect.

That said, I have never used `widows` property :p But, I kind of understand it.
It was created to be used in paged media, like... a css for print.

For example:

```css
@media print {
  p {widows: 4;}
}
```

This will made that, when the page is printed and a paragraph starts and the end of a page and we need to continue printing it at next page, if there are only 2 remaining lines, like that is less that the widows lines we allow (4 lines), instead of printing that 2 remaining lines alone (widows) in the next page, we will move (and print) that last paragraph to the start of the new printed page.